# ESXi 5.5 on unlisted AMD A10 6800K possible?

Tags: virtualization, esxi

I've done some initial googling..  and found AMD's A10 6800K supports virtualization via AMD-V. I'd like to install ESXI 5.5 on a USB thumbdrive to drive two+ VM's running Lubuntu.

Has anyone seen the AMD A10 APU line used for baremetal hosting?

```
AMD A10 APU 6800K
8GB DDR3 non ECC RAM
350GB HDD old spin drive (Sata I?III? unknown)
```

I want to get started but afraid I'll wipe my current linux instance if it goes bad.

Comment: Why would software ran on the host os wipe the host os?  If you are that worried backup your data.

Comment: If ESXi doesn't work out, try OpenXen Server, it's not as polished (last time I tried, anyway), but it seems a bit less strict about hardware support. You can also patch in your own drivers to your ESXi installer, it's not really easy, but ESXi does run on Linux.

Comment: Ramhound.. I need to install ESXi don't I?  I already have the data backed up.. it's the matter of reinstalling that backup if ESXi doesn't work out.

Comment: I repurposed my A10-5800K HTPC to an ESXi host a couple years ago. All my VMs hum along just fine. Low power, low cost and it hasn't skipped a beat.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The AMD APU based system is currently humming along.  Now I need to research how to add more drives.

Consumer grade HW required me to do some tweaking of the VMware install .iso .. See here :

http://www.bussink.ch/?p=1228

> The ESXi 5.5.0 Build 1331820  that came out yesterday, did not include
>   any Realtek R8168 or R8169 driver in it. So if your homelab ESXi host
>   only has these Realtek 8168 network cards, you need to build a custom
>   ISO.
>
> The most simple tool to use is Andreas Peetz’s (@VFrontDE)  ESXi
>   Customizer 2.7.1 tool. The ESXi Customizer tool allows you to select
>   the ESXi 5.5.0 ISO file and include into it a new Driver in .vib
>   format.
>
> You can then download and extract the VMware Bookbank NET-R8168 driver
>   from vSphere 5.1 ISO or download it from the following link for your
>   convenience.

http://www.v-front.de/p/esxi-customizer.html